# How to fetch Feedburner RSS Feed subscribers count in PHP & WordPress

Tags: php, count, subscription, feedburner

I have been using a WordPress based PHP function for quite a while now to retrieve the Feedburner subscriber count to be able to display the subscriber count as text.

Here is the function:

```
/**
 * Fetch Feedburner RSS Feed Subscribers.
 *
 * @param string $feed The feed to fetch.
 * @return int of Feedburner RSS subscribers.
 */
public function get_feedburner_subcribers($feedburner_username){
    $xml = wp_remote_get('http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=' .$feedburner_username);

    if(is_wp_error($xml))
        return false;

    try {
        $sxe = @new SimpleXMLElement($xml['body']);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // SimpleXMLElement::__construct produces an E_WARNING error message for
        // each error found in the XML data and throws an exception if errors
        // were detected. Catch any exception and return failure (NULL).
        return;
    }

    return self::format(intval($sxe->feed->entry['circulation']));
}
```

All was working great until recently when the function no longer returns any value.

If I directly paste the URL `http://feedburner.google.com/api/awareness/1.0/GetFeedData?uri=my-feedburner-id` I get a Google Error 404 page.

Has Google changed things again and if so is there any other way to retrieve the Feedburner count?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Feedburner API](https://developers.google.com/feedburner/) is [no longer available](http://googlecode.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/spring-cleaning-for-some-of-our-apis.html). It was shut down on 20 October 2012 (more detail [here](http://www.nevillehobson.com/2012/09/09/prepare-for-goodbye-feedburner-in-october-2012/), including the shutdown date.)

Comment: Thanks Matt for that info. That is disappointing. So is there any alternative to getting the Feedburner count that you know of?

Comment: Not that I know of. And there's fairly [widespread concern](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=moving+away+from+feedburner&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) that Feedburner itself will be disappearing at some point. You may want to do some research and decide whether you want to invest any more time in the service at all.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I appreciate your time.